# Php equation: variable minus same rounded variable, possible?

Tags: php, variables, var, equation

I need to echo number(variable) in two ways and i need help with code for this equation.
Example:

Variable is 5003

First echo has to be: 5000 (rounded)

Second echo has to be just the rounded digits: 3

So i want to know if and how can i achieve this equation, im thinking among lines of: variable(5003) minus rounded variable(5000) equals 3

So that way if variable is lets say 15009

Fist will be 15000
Second will be 9

I hope this make sense, thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the [round<sup>*PHP*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function:

You can have negative decimal points like this:

```
round(5003, -3);  // returns 5000
round(15009, -3); // returns 15000
```

To figure out the difference you can do like this:

```
$input = 5003
$x = $input;
$y = round($input, -3);
$z = $x - $y; // z is now 3
```

PHP is not a mathematical language, so it cannot solve equations for you.

You can make a more general solution like this:

```
$inputs = [
    5003,
    15009,
    55108,
    102010
];

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    $decimals = floor(log10($input)) - 1;
    $rounded = round($input, -1 * $decimals);
    echo "$input - $rounded = " . ($input - $rounded) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
5003 - 5000 = 3
15009 - 15000 = 9
55108 - 55000 = 108
102010 - 100000 = 2010
```

Comment: Yes, thank you but can i use it in equation? Example: x=5003, y=Round(x, -3) and so z=x-y ...will z be 3? Thank you

Comment: I updated the answer. You can adjust the equation part to fit your needs @MartinSprušanský

Comment: Thank you, i belive that is exactly what i needed, im posting this from mobile so i cant test it atm but im sure it will work, i will report back, thank you once again for amazing answer!

Comment: @MartinSprušanský please accept the answer if it is what you needed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to round the last three digits:

```
$input = 5003;

$rounded = (int)(5003 / 1000) * 1000;
$rest = $input - $rounded;

echo($rounded . "\n" . $rest);
```

This results in:

```
5000
3
```